# UITableView section's header hight: how to smoothly change it in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a smooth appearance of the tableView section header by changing it height multiplier from 0 to 1 by this method:

> .sectionHeaderHeight.multiply(by: _) where _ should be a CGFloat.

The code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {       
   tableView.sectionHeaderHeight.multiply(by: _)
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the header can take only 0 (is hidden) or 1.

Everything more that 1 ruins the UI, everything between 0 and 1 generates an `error`:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:],
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableViewRowData.m:443

Answer (score 4):

To change header section height override the method `heightForHeaderInSection`.

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
```

this will probably solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to animate when it will be displayed, I'd suggest adding a transition when setting the header view itself.
Please add the animation of your choice

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let aHeader = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
    let header = aHeader as UIView
    var headerFrame = tableView.frame
    headerFrame.size.height = 100
    header.frame = headerFrame

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 1.0;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //choose your animation
    header.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
    return header
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! However it was empty, as clean UIView doesn't have text label. I fixed it this way:

let aHeader = UITableViewHeaderFooterView()
let header = aHeader as UIView